# Magento 2: Create a custom order view page

Tags: magento2, module, orders

In magento 2 is there any way to create same order view page in custom module?
I want to create a custom order view page where I have to display some more data but not want to display on core (order view page).
So for that I need to create a custom a page same as order view page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Create frontname_controllerdirectory_controllerclass.xml inside your module `view/adminhtml/layout`

Then copy all the layout of sales_order_view.xml from `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout`

Then add custom block or your logic you want to implement and create redirect to your link `frontname_controllerdirectory_controllerclass` and create View.php class inside Controller/Adminhtml then define

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class View extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Namespace_ModuleName::actions_view';

    const PAGE_TITLE = 'Add page title here';

    public function execute()
    {
        $order = $this->_initOrder();
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($order) {
            try {
                $resultPage = $this->_initAction();
                $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Page title'));
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Exception occurred during order load'));
                $resultRedirect->setPath('yourfrontname/order/index');
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
            $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(sprintf("#%s", $order->getIncrementId()));
            return $resultPage;
        }
        $resultRedirect->setPath('yourfrontname/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```